# Greasemonkey script not setting innerHTML properly

Tags: greasemonkey

My grease monkey script is the following:

`document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML = "<b>asdfdsfa</b>";`

alert( document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML );

When I run the script, the alert says:

`&lt;html&gt;b&lt;asdfdsfa&lt;/b&lt;`

And the text that I see is

`<html><b>asdfsda</b>`

Does anyone know what I have to do to have the correct stuff displayed (ie. bolded "asdfsda")

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What is the doctype of the page you are changing?

Also, have you looked at DOM methods?

e.g. document.createElement('B');

Comment: the doctype is text/plain

I have not looked into document.createElement(...).

Comment: From wiki.greasespot.net/Code_snippets: ".innerHTML seems to be sensitive to document.contentType. When the type is text/plain the .innerHTML setter does not parse its argument into DOM nodes, but instead returns #text nodes. The setter seems to work fine for types such as text/html or application/xhtml+xml but where and how it works is undocumented."

document.createElement("b") works. Set the text with .textContent = ""

Comment: var myB = document.createElement('B');
myB.appendChild(document.createTextNode('asdfsda'));

Answer (score 0):

You have to type .textContent instead of .innerHTML if you don't want to view the ascii code :) have a nice time!